# OpenSSL: can't build in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, openssl, visual-c++-2010

I have downloaded the latest OpenSSL source package. I want to build it with VC++ 2010 x64. Following the instructions doesn't seem to work. Configure step looks fine, but then:

C:\1>ms\do_win64a.bat

C:\1>perl util\mkfiles.pl  1>MINFO

C:\1>perl ms\uplink.pl win64a  1>ms\uptable.asm

C:\1>ml64 -c -Foms\uptable.obj ms\uptable.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembling: ms\uptable.asm

C:\1>perl util\mk1mf.pl no-asm VC-WIN64A  1>ms\nt.mak
no rule for crypto\md4 at util\mk1mf.pl line 907.

C:\1>perl util\mk1mf.pl dll no-asm VC-WIN64A  1>ms\ntdll.mak
no rule for crypto\md4 at util\mk1mf.pl line 907.

C:\1>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 libeay  1>ms\libeay32.def

C:\1>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 ssleay  1>ms\ssleay32.def

Win 32 (do_ms) output looks a bit different, but "no rule for crypto\md4 at util\mk1mf.pl line 907" remains.

Could anyone help me in building the library or share vc2010-built binaries?.. Or a VS2010 project file for the library?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to eol (end of lines). The solution is to patch mk1mf.pl to make it remove the carriage-return:

```
Index: mk1mf.pl
===================================================================
--- mk1mf.pl    (revision 88908)
+++ mk1mf.pl    (working copy)
@@ -315,7 +315,7 @@
 for (;;)
        {
        chop;

+       s/\r$//; #remove carriage return too!
        ($key,$val)=/^([^=]+)=(.*)/;
        if ($key eq "RELATIVE_DIRECTORY")
                {
```

Found the solution in openssl users mailing:

http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.openssl.users/browse_thread/thread/42a8f226f1fc279f)

Comment: This helped me with compiling ms\do_ms without "no rule for crypto\md4 at util\mk1mf.pl line 907" errors.

Answer (score 7):

The patch provided above works, but a better solution is to use use ActivePerl, as recommended in the OpenSSL documentation.

http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

Other perl builds such as the MSYS build will give you this error.

In order to figure out if you're using ActivePerl, run perl.exe --version in a command prompt. It should say something like:

```
Binary build 1601 [296175] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
```

Comment: this absolutely works. I had git\bin on my PATH, so it was using an MSYS version of Perl. I put ActiveState first on my PATH.

Comment: @yano, thank you.  For Windows users, `where perl` will show the order of perl path entries.  I also had git's perl in front of my ActivePerl installation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using MSYS perl, which follows unix-style line endings.
You should use sources extracted from .tar.gz by MSYS tools:

```
  $ tar zxvf openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
```

or checkout from git with configuration "autocrlf false" set before checkout:

```
  > git config --global core.autocrlf false
  > git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  I fixed it by issuing 'find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;' from my Git bash shell to change the line endings.  (Note: Mind that find is something different from a dos prompt.)