# Building nginx in Windows 7 with MSYS

Tags: visual-c++, build, nginx, msys

I have Windows 7 Pro x86 with Visual Studio 2010 Pro. Also I have MinGW in c:\MinGW.
I want to build nginx under windows using Visual C++. I follow [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html) guide.

1. I run cmd under Administrator, then I call "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
2. In cmd I run C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat
3. I cd to nginx source direcotry and run configure script, before I downloaded prerequisites.
4. Then I run nmake -f objs/Makefile

The result is the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

'install' is up-to-date
    cl -O2  -W4 -WX -nologo -MT -Zi -DFD_SETSIZE=1024 -DNO_SYS_TYPES_H 
       -Ycng x_config.h -Fpobjs/ngx_config.pch -c -I src/core-I src/event
       -I src/event/mod ules  -I src/os/win32  -I objs/lib/pcre-8.32  
       -I objs/lib/openssl/openssl/include -I objs/lib/zlib-1.2.7  -I objs
       -I src/http  -I src/http/modules -I src/mail -Foobjs/ngx_pch.obj 
       objs/ngx_pch.c ngx_pch.c

    cl -c -O2  -W4 -WX -nologo -MT -Zi -DFD_SETSIZE=1024 -DNO_SYS_TYPES_H 
       -Y ungx_config.h -Fpobjs/ngx_config.pch -I src/core-I src/event  
       -I src/event/mod ules  -I src/os/win32  -I objs/lib/pcre-8.32  
       -I objs/lib/openssl/openssl/include  -I objs/lib/zlib-1.2.7  -I objs
       -I src/http  -I src/http/modules -I src/mail -Foobjs/src/core/nginx.obj
       src/core/nginx.c nginx.c

c:\nginx\source\src\event\ngx_event_openssl.h(15) : fatal error C1083:
Cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0\VC\BI N\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
```

But OpenSSL is located in C:\nginx\source\objs\lib\openssl

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

The problem is related to eol (end of lines) handling of certain files with the Perl build used.
You should not use the MSYS Perl build.
Instead you should use ActivePerl or StrawberryPerl, as indicated in the [guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html).
Be sure though that the PATH points to the appropriate Perl distribution, prior to the MSYS Perl.

```
export PATH=/appropriate/perl/dist:$PATH
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680189/openssl-cant-build-in-vc-2010) helped me solve the problem.

Comment: For me the solution was to rename perl.exe in msys\bin to something like perl_UNUSED.exe so that Strawberry Perl would be used instead. (Even though paths to Strawberry Perl were added, and came prior to the msys paths... it was still picking up msys perl for some reason.)

Use "which perl" to verify the correct version is being used.