# Making a call to a Chef server from Windows PE

Tags: python, windows, chef-infra

I have Python Windows install scripts that run in Windows PE. During a re-install (with the same machine name) the chef-client will fail since the client cert already exists. I am attempting to delete the client from the chef server during a re-install in Window PE.

I found [pychef](https://github.com/Scalr/pychef) that will delete the client key. The problem is that it required OpenSSL which in turn requires [Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29). I have been unsuccessful in getting the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables loaded in Windows PE. I have tried just to copy the DLLs but that throws the following error.

```
The application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is 
incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line 
sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
```

Is there a way to get the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables into Windows PE?

Or to entirely side step the issue, is there a way to make a call to the Chef server without using OpenSSL?

I am using Python 3.4.1 and Windows PE 3.0.

EDIT: I found a [RSA library](http://stuvel.eu/rsa) that is pure python. I made an attempt to use that library instead of OpenSSL by replacing the `Key` class.

```
import rsa

class Key(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            if key.startswith('-----'):
                # PEM formatted text
                key_data = key
            else:
                key_data = open(key, 'rb').read()
        else:
            key_data = key.read()

        self.private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(key_data)

    def private_encrypt(self, data):
        return rsa.encrypt(data.encode('utf-8'), self.private_key)
```

The code runs but I get back `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`.

```
Invalid signature for user or client 'testcert'
```

I don't know too much about encryption so I assume I am just using the library wrong or need to change some setting. Will the pure python library work for talking to the Chef server? If so, what is the proper way to use it?

Comment: It isn't really helpful, but I don't know if PyChef even runs on Python 3.

Comment: There is a fork the makes the changes. That's the repo I linked too. It's basically running 2to3 and fixing a couple str to bytes errors. I haven't tested it fully but It works for what I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compiling OpenSSL statically.

There is a bug in the build scripts that need to be fixed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730234/1218859

After that small change is applied, the following commands work to build statically.

```
> perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm no-shared
> ms\do_ms
> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```